# Drush Not recognizing it's in a drupal root

Tags: drush

[Drush](http://drush.ws/) commands seem to succeed but don't.

For example, `drush dl module` results in:

> Install location /doc_root/feeds_tamper already exists. Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n): y
>   Project feeds_tamper (7.x-1.0-beta5) downloaded to /doc_root/feeds_tamper.
>   Project feeds_tamper contains 2 modules: feeds_tamper_ui, feeds_tamper.

However, it's the wrong download location, and there is no feeds tamper in that location.

Drush status returns:

> PHP configuration: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
>   Drush version: 5.9

I am in the document root of the Drupal site.

This is on Windows with Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

If your settings.php file is inside a directory named default, then Drush will find it whenever your current working directory is anywhere inside the document root.  However, if settings.php is in some other directory, then you must either cd to the directory that contains settings.php, or identify your site via some other technique -- for example, by specifying --uri=mysite.com, or by using a Drush site alias.

Comment: `-l mysite.com` is shorter :)